# How to make reverse for temporary url?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have source url `domain.ex/dir/video.mp4`

I have temporary url `domain.ex/vlink/temp.mp4` which I need to "connect" to source `domain.ex/dir/video.mp4`

The same domain. But files have different names, `video.mp4 != temp.mp4`

I use `nginx` to serve source url

```
location /dir/ {
    alias /media/videos/;
                }
```

My current `urls.py`

```
path('vlink/<str:temp>', views.vlink, name='vlink'),
```

`view.py`

```
def vlink(request, temp):
    # drop extension mp4
    s = temp.split('.')[0] 
    # I retrieve original file name
    vid = TmpUrl.objects.filter(tmp_url = s).values('orig').first()
    v = vid['orig']
    the_url = '/dir/'+v+'.mp4'    
    return redirect(the_url)
```

`template.html`

```
<video>
<source src="/vlink/{{vid}}.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

I don't need simple redirect. I need to hide source url.

What I need: when user click play, the browser shows tmp url  and play vid without redirect to source.

How to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe you could configure it directly in `nginx`. At least `location /vlink/` Eventually you would have to use `send_file()` to read from disk and send it.

Comment: @furas, Maybe. Can you give me idea, pls? Tnx

Comment: maybe you should use `location /vlink/` instead of `location /dir/`. And `nginx` should have module `rewrite` to change links.

Comment: @furas, I thought about it, but  files have different names, video.mp4 != temp.mp4 source file name stored in db. location /dir/temp.mp4 will 404

Comment: module `rewrite` is for rewriting links. I think it can replace `video` with `temp`

Comment: frankly, I would rather run SQL query to rename all names in database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found solution. It's internal redirect in Nginx + X-Accel-Redirect in Django.

`views.py`

```
def vlink(request, temp):        
    s = temp.split('.')[0]
    vid = TmpUrl.objects.filter(tmp_url = s).values('orig').first()
    v = vid['orig']
    the_url = '/dir/'+v+'.mp4'        
    response = HttpResponse(status=200)
    response['Content-Type'] = 'video/mp4'
    response['X-Accel-Redirect'] = the_url
    return response
```

`nginx.conf`

```
location /dir/ {
 internal;
 alias /media/videos/;
          }
```